# can a part-time contract good enough to apply work permit after graduated in local school with a job seeking visa?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, freelance, application-status

I graduated with my art master in local German University, having my job seeking visa and it goes to my 17 months, I got a part-time contract (Arbeitsvertrag für gewerbliche Arbeitnehmer)which is not related to my study ( the contract has a monthly salary, included all tax, pension and public insurance public holiday etc)also I have 2 letter of intents from museum and art studio to offer me freelance jobs . Last week, I have an artist visa appointment,but once the officer saw my part-time contract, she rejected my freelance visa application and asked me to submit all paper and contract to an email " lea. berlin" then I will get my working permit in 15 days, after that I was kicked out from the office.

I am now super super worry, I search online and trying to seek for advice about if a work visa in Germany is so easy to get in 15 days with only a part-time contract by sending an email!?

Also. Even all my document are well prepared, there are more than 20 small files which cannot be zip in one email and for sure that will be over 25MB  storage by sending one gmail. I cannot imagine officers could open a dropbox link or google drives to check my doc one by one. (let me know if I am underestimated their patience)

Then, I immediately book another appointment online for another freelance visa, I checked online, there are some article mentioned that when applicant get an appointment before their visa expired  (next month), they can still stay in German legally until the appointment.

Comment: What type of work is your part-time contract for exactly? From https://visaguide.world/europe/germany-visa/long-stay/freelancer/ “It might happen that if they are not sure your freelance profession really falls under the category of Artist Freelance Visa, your application will be sent to the Federal Employment Agency and it will take up to three months to review everything”

Comment: From my experience, the number of working hours per week does not matter that much. What matters is the salary (if it is enough to fund yourself, then fine). If you need freelance in addition to "residence permit with the purpose of work", you might ask a permission separately (for example, check § 21 Absatz 6 Aufenthaltsgesetzes), cause this type of the residence permit might not include permission to work on your own. Also you might need to check your part-time contract if it allows you to freelance in your free time. P.S. I'm not a lawyer...